# Hazelcast - ClassC

Tags: java, classcastexception, hazelcast

I'm trying to use Hazelcast on a Wildfly 8.2. I've taken a simple example, but I get:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hazelcast.jca.HazelcastConnectionImpl cannot be cast to com.hazelcast.jca.HazelcastConnection

From

```
private HazelcastConnection getConnection() {
    try {
        return  (HazelcastConnection)connectionFactory.getConnection();
    } catch (ResourceException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while getting Hazelcast connection", e);
    }
}
```

In my pom.xml I have

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-jca</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sounds like you have the hazelcast-jca also on container level since it seems like you end up having to different classloaders (my guess), therefore you cannot cast HazelcastConnectionImpl[cl1] that implements HazelcastConnection[cl1] to a HazelcastConnection[cl2] interface.

Comment: I assume you have deployed the Hazelcast Resource Adapter into WildFly? Is it deployed as a module? If so, try to scope Hazelcast dependencies as "provided" in your pom.xml + your application should declare a dependency on the Hazelcast module.

Comment: To a start I had provided but then I got ClassNotFound, then I tried to remove it. It looks like it's not able to find the jar's in module at deploy time but at runtime both are found - just tried with provided again - and i get  **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/jca/HazelcastConnection**

Comment: I did like this **http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/samplejboss7configuration.html** , but had to add **<module name="sun.jdk"/>** to the module.xml to be able to deploy the rar file

Comment: Made it work, by keeping the provided scope for both hazelcast dependencies and adding a dependency to the hazelcast module in my jboss-deployment-structure.xml in in WEB-INF

Comment: that's great to know! If I understand it correctly you had to do 2 changes:
1. add a dependency on sun.jdk to the Hazelcast RA module
2. add a dependency on the Hazelcast module to your application?

Is it correct? Is there any other change you had to make in order to deploy & use the Hazelcast RA?

Comment: Yes to deploy the rar file I had to add dependency to sun.jdk in the module.xml. And I had to add a dependency to com.hazelcast in my jboss-deployment-structure.xml - this made my problem with HazelcastConnectionImpl cast go away. In the pom.xml my denpendencies scope are set to

Answer (score 0):

Remove all hazelcast dependency and add in pom file

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```